# Shared hit cache in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, caching

I'm experimenting with the EXPLAIN command and trying to find out what the `shared hit` is.

```
Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..18334.00 rows=1000000 width=37) (actual time=0.030..90.500 rows=1000000 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=512 read=7822
Total runtime: 116.080 ms
```

I've noticed that the more shared hit number we have the faster a query is being executed. But what is that? As far as I got, `shared read` is just reading from a physical storage like `RAID` or `SSD`. But why is the `shared hit` faster? Is it stored inside RAM or where?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name How is it possible the values came from memory (shared in the case) without reading the memory? I don't understand...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory_%28interprocess_communication%29) the shared memory concept you talked about?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`shared hit` essentially means the value has already been cached in the main memory of the computer and it was not necessary to read this from the hard disk.

Accessing the main memory (RAM) is **much** faster than reading values from the hard disk. And that's why the query is faster the more share hits it has.

Immediately after starting Postgres, none of the data is available in the main memory (RAM) and everything needs to be read from the hard disk.

Consider this step from an execution plan:

```
  ->  Seq Scan on products.product_price  (cost=0.00..3210.27 rows=392273 width=0) (actual time=0.053..103.958 rows=392273 loops=1)
        Output: product_id, valid_from, valid_to, price
        Buffers: shared read=2818
        I/O Timings: read=48.382
```

The part "Buffers: shared read=2818" means that 2818 blocks (each 8k) had to be read from the hard disk (and that took 48ms - I have a SSD). Those 2818 blocks were stored in the cache (the "[shared buffers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-resource.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-RESOURCE-MEMORY)") so that the next time they are needed the database does not need to read them (again) from the (slow) hard disk.

When I re-run that statement the plan changes to:

```
  ->  Seq Scan on products.product_price  (cost=0.00..3210.27 rows=392273 width=0) (actual time=0.012..45.690 rows=392273 loops=1)
        Output: product_id, valid_from, valid_to, price
        Buffers: shared hit=2818
```

Which means that those 2818 blocks that the previous statement were still in the main memory (=RAM) and Postgres did not need to read them from the hard disk.

"memory" always refers to the main memory (RAM) built into the computer and directly accessible to the CPU - as opposed to "external storage".

There are several presentations on how Postgres manages the shared buffers:

- http://de.slideshare.net/EnterpriseDB/insidepostgressharedmemory2015
- http://momjian.us/main/writings/pgsql/hw_performance/
- https://2ndquadrant.com/media/pdfs/talks/InsideBufferCache.pdf (*very* technical)
- http://raghavt.blogspot.de/2012/04/caching-in-postgresql.html

Comment: hi @a_horse_with_no_name 
First, thanks for your response. 

Is there a way to force postgres read some data  to memory automaticaly after postgres restart ? 

Our database has some big tables (with Million of rows). 
The first time we access to the data it takes  7 to 12 seconds. But  just after,  it takes less than second to acces the some data!

I think it's because the loading at the first execution of data in the RAM. 
Is there a way to optimize  that behavior ? 
Is   it à good idea to load automaticaly data into RAM (so for all our customer we'll be sur they are not impacted.

Comment: @soung: that's what [pg_prewarm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgprewarm.html) is for.

Comment: thank you @a_horse_with_no_name. this is what i'm looking for.
i have tested it. it seems working fine.

But  there is a little thing i don't understand. After emptying the cache, when I restart postgres  and do a 'explain analyze', the data seems are readed from buffer cache (there is a line with buffer hit in explain analyze). i don't know if this is caused by prewarm extension. I was supposing that prewarm  only keep in the cache  blocks readed by precedent sql queries. i'm right ?

Comment: Hi, I do not understand why in an execution plan the I/O timing is bigger than execution time
I/O Timings: read=6418.986                                                                                            Planning Time: 0.410 ms                                                                                                           Execution Time: 5355.107 ms2
Any idea?